# What is the best way to merge hashes?

Tags: ruby

I'm having two similar hashes. The first one looks like:

```
{'1'=>
   {'ab'=>{'a'=>1, 'b'=>4},
   {'bc'=>{'b'=>2, 'c'=>1},
   ...
}
```

The second one is pretty similar:

```
{'1'=>
   {'ab'=>{'v'=>1},
   {'bc'=>{'v'=>2},
   ...
}
```

I'd like to merge these like:

```
{'1'=>
   {'ab'=>{'a'=>1, 'b'=>4, 'v'=>1},
   {'bc'=>{'b'=>2, 'c'=>1, 'v'=>2},
   ...
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Is there more than one key at the second level? You should probably fix the syntax errors to be more clear in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Hash#deep_merge` from ActiveSupport. https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge

If you don't want to depend on active_support gem or not willing to monkey-patch core classes, you can just copy the algorithm from the AS and adapt to your needs.

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb, line 21
  def deep_merge!(other_hash, &block)
    other_hash.each_pair do |current_key, other_value|
      this_value = self[current_key]

      self[current_key] = if this_value.is_a?(Hash) && other_value.is_a?(Hash)
        this_value.deep_merge(other_value, &block)
      else
        if block_given? && key?(current_key)
          block.call(current_key, this_value, other_value)
        else
          other_value
        end
      end
    end

    self
  end
```

UPDATE:

I'm not sure why the answer was downvoted. Here is `deep_merge` in action:

```
[10] pry(main)> a = {'1'=>
[10] pry(main)*   {'ab'=>{'a'=>1, 'b'=>4},
[10] pry(main)*   'bc'=>{'b'=>2, 'c'=>1}}
[10] pry(main)* };
[11] pry(main)>
[12] pry(main)> b = {'1'=>
[12] pry(main)*   {'ab'=>{'v'=>1},
[12] pry(main)*   'bc'=>{'v'=>2}}
[12] pry(main)* };
[13] pry(main)>
[14] pry(main)> a.deep_merge(b)
=> {"1"=>{"ab"=>{"a"=>1, "b"=>4, "v"=>1}, "bc"=>{"b"=>2, "c"=>1, "v"=>2}}}
[15] pry(main)>
```

*Exactly* what OP needs.

Comment: Yeah. nowadays we are to bring a whole Rails or copy-paste a 15-LOC method from there instead of writing a trivial one-liner ourselves.

Comment: I know, I know.

Answer (score 3):

For these simple case:

```
h1.merge(h2) do |_, v1, v2|
  v1.merge(v2) { |_, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) }
end
#⇒ {"1"=>{"ab"=>{"a"=>1, "b"=>4, "v"=>1},
#         "bc"=>{"b"=>2, "c"=>1, "v"=>2}}}
```

Also note that what you have posted as an input **are not** valid ruby objects.

Comment: Conclusion: if `merge` doesn't help, just keep calling it until you get the desired result.

Comment: @Stefan I have tried, but sometimes the stack complains with cryptic “too deep” message :)

Comment: Wow it is amazing to me that a question titled *"What is the best way to merge hashes?"* resulted in `Hash#merge`. Who woulda thunk it? Maybe you should have used `Hash#update` just to be cool . on a side note though your piped variables should probably have different names as it makes it confusing as to the reference inside a double iteration

Comment: @engineersmnky what would you think about `[h1, h2].each { |h| h.extend(Module.new { alias_method :+, :merge })` and then calling `+` with a block? Would it be even cooler?

Comment: That would definitely be cooler if it worked since it cannot be interpreted :)

Comment: @engineersmnky sure it can: `h1.+(h2) do |_, v1, v2| ... end`.

Comment: This portion `Module.new { alias_method :+, :merge }` raises a `NoMethodError` (at least for me on 2.2)

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah, it should be `def +; merge; end` since the empty module does not have a `merge` method defined and `alias_method` checks that.